# Chapter title page with bibliographic footnote

Tags: header-footer, memoir, chapters, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I'm working on setting up a document class (based on memoir) for an edited volume. As the footer or as footnote for the first page of the chapter, I need to have the bibliograhic reference for that chapter. I'd like to pull that from a bibtex/biblatex entry, but not have it show in the bibliograhy.

So, this is a two-part question:

1. suggestion for either modifying `\@makechapterhead` or otherwise generate a footnote-like entity (i.e. without a footnbote mark) to include the `\fullcite` output at the bottom of the page, and
2. how to do it in such a way that it isn't done as a citation in the chapter's bibliography?

**Edit** Work in progress, but part way there...
After reviewing the client's requirements, apparently I'd misread a bit. They want the volume info in the footer/footnote and not the actual citation. That saves a good bit of fiddling with the biblatex bit.

What they want is something that looks like the output of (based on the answer from @Johannes_B):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol} % only way found to get pagewidth footnote 
                      % with two column layout

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\volumedetail}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
        \makefootmark\raggedright##1}
    \setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0em}
    \setlength{\footmarksep}{-\footmarkwidth}
    \setlength{\footparindent}{0em}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}
    \footnotetext{\raggedright{#1}}
    \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Wombat, wombat, wombat}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\volumedetail{In \emph{Testing 1-2-3 -- A Big Contributed Volume}, edited by A.N. Editor, Proceedings of the Conference N\textsuperscript{o}\space999, \copyright\space1999 by  University of Somewhare Press. All rights reserved.}
\lipsum 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

So, now what it look like I need to do is either setup a `memoir` chapterstyle, make a customization to `\chapter`, or make a custom chapter `pagestyle` to automate the output during layout (i.e. pull the volume infor from `\title{}`, `\author{}`, etc.

Comment: can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @LukasCB, That's just it... I don't really know what an MWE would involve for this. My thought is (using biblatex), to set it as a footnote-like item to the `\chapter{}` section with `\fullcite{ChapKey}`, but need to exclude it from the `\printbibliography` bibliography list. After thinking through it, I'm not looking for a pagestyle issue (I'll edit the question) as much as a modification to the code for `\chapter {}`... but most pertnently, I don't know how to exclude a citation from the biblio.

Comment: I am really not sure what your output is supposed to look like. Maybe you are just looking for `\footfullcite`? Why changing the chapterhead?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I have no way to post an image of what I'm looking for (net media filters at work), but it's fairly common in academic journals and contributed volumes (e.g. conference proceedings) for the first page of each chapter to have a full bibliographic reference at the bottom of the page. I could just add a footnote after the `\chapter{}` entry, but would need to have it not have a footnote mark. It's also very possible that I'm overthinking this, and there's a very simple solution that just isn't occuring to me...

Comment: @Johannes_B, I've edited the question, since the problem changed a bit, and included an MWE mockup of what I'm aiming at. The bib citation reference requirement was dropped, so now I'm more looking at a modified chaptersyle (I think?) to automatically insert the footnote/footer. STill no way to post an image, but the mwe  compiles to what the output should look like.

Comment: Looks good, what do you want to change?

Comment: While this gets the general layout for a one-off, the main goal is to set up a custom `.cls` based on memoir. To that end, what I'm looking for is a way to either set up one of memoir's chaptersyles or a modified `\chapter`-like command for the chapter page to be set up like this by default (i.e. rather than needing to do it for each chapter individually, I'm also trying to figure building in chapter author commands as well). The volume I'm working on has 10 chapters, and it looks like they're planning to do more volumes like this down the road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know what is needed. But here is a first suggestion and starting point.

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @inproceedings{wombat,
        author    = {Walter Wombat and Carl Capybara},
        title     = {Looking at a watch for exactly 17.234 hours},
        subtitle  = {Will you get crazy?},
        booktitle = {Journal of madness},
        date      = {2016-10-06},
        keywords  = {authordetail},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newcommand{\authordetail}[1]{\begingroup\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}\footnotetext{\fullcite{#1}}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Wombat, wombat, wombat}
\authordetail{wombat}
\blindtext\footnote{Wombats are really cuddly.}
\printbibliography[notkeyword=authordetail]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's nearly perfect... I'll have to do some editing of the formatting for `\authordetail`, but something like this should work very well. Thank you.